# How to find the mean color of a connected component?

Tags: opencv, contour

It seems like OpenCV does not have a direct method to find mean color of a connected component -or a contour.

I used `pointPolygonTest`; saved all the points and their colors inside my contour; than applied `mean` method to calculate the average hue value. Problem is, it is so slow. Is there a fast way to achieve this? Are there any ideas, or available methods to use?

Comment: you can use cv::mean function with mask.

Comment: That would be a good enhancement, but complexity arises from pointPolygonTest. I think I will exit the loop after I find 50 points and average them. I heard about a blob library addon for opencv. Is the cvbloblib does this fast? I might check its source code.

Comment: you don't need pointpolygon. Find the contour. Create a mask with that contour. Then apply function cv::mean().

Comment: I don't know if it is the right approach for C++ api, but to create the mask, I used `fillpoly` with that contour on a black image, then used `mean` within this mask. It is much more faster now.

Comment: you can use `drawcontours` also.

Comment: yes, you can create a mask like this `Mat mask = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8U);` and then [`drawContours(mask, contours, idx, color, CV_FILLED, 8);`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontours#cv.DrawContours)

Comment: totally forgot about filled drawing option, thanks